# What little things do I need to do before deploying a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, config

**EDIT**

What small things which are too easy to overlook do I need to do before deploying a rails application?

I have set up [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101275/what-do-i-need-to-do-on-deployment-of-a-rails-application) for any task that takes more than a minute or two, and so ought to be scheduled into a deployment process. In this question I'm mostly concerned with on-line config options and similar, that can be done, but are often left out in during the development cycle because they don't make any difference until deployment

Comment: nice question!  Now I would recommend if you partially answer your multiple choice question, let other people repeat your answers (I was going to add several points but got down voted for repeat)

Comment: Ok, sorry - probably me being pedantic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Freeze the gems you are using `rake gems:unpack`
- Change the secret in `config/environment.rb`
- Filter sensitive informtion like passwords: in `app/controllers/application.rb`
  `filter_parameter_logging :password, :password_confirmation`

Answer (score 4):

- Ensure the DB is setup on your production server
- Set up capistrano to deploy your app properly

  - Run a capistrano dry-run
- Ensure Rails is packed into your vendor/rails folder
- Ensure all gems are frozen in your app or installed on your prod server
- Run your tests on the production machine

Answer (score 2):

- Include google analytics snippet (or other analytics)

Answer (score 1):

- Check the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html), and add any indexes to your models which are causing full-table traverses.
- Also

  grep -ril FIXME

Comment: even better for the also: rake notes:fixme

Answer (score 1):

Set up the files and folders to be shared between deployed copies of the app, including (but not limited to) view caches, database config, maintenance page...

Answer (score 0):

These aren't really Rails-specific deployment-tasks, but I have seen them overlooked too many times for deployed systems:

- Backups; admittedly, this can end up being a big task, but it need not be.  Simply scheduling nightly backups of the database and software is often sufficient.
- Testing the restoration procedure
- Log rotation and archiving
- Exception notification

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the place you are deploying to has the RAILS_ENV variable properly set. Either through the environment, or through a capistrano callback.
- Make sure your tests are all passing by running rake spec, shoulda, unit tests, or whatever you are using to test.
- Unpack your gems using rake gems:unpack
- Decide whether you need to freeze Rails. rake rails:freeze:gems
- Double check that dependencies are installed on the server if you need more than just gems (memcached, mail server, etc)
- If you are using MySQL, compile and install the C-based MySQL library on the server (this could take longer than a few minutes, but typically is fairly quick if all dependencies are satisfied).
- If you are using git, push your code to the master branch. Tag it if necessary.
- If you are using SVN, tag the release.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [very good article for deploying rails app using ubuntu](http://blog.dhavalparikh.co.in/2009/09/deploy-or-configure-rails-on-a-ubuntu-server/).